# Oracle - script for immediate session kill (I get an error!)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have written a simple script that will kill oracle session immediate:

```
DECLARE
    v_kill VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    FOR v_kill IN
    (SELECT
            'alter system kill session '''
            ||sid
            ||','
            ||serial#
            ||'''',
            'immediate;'
                    FROM
            v$session
                WHERE
            sql_id='sql_id_here'
    )
    LOOP
        EXECUTE immediate v_kill;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Unfortunately I get an error which makes me stuck with this issue:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: linia 18, kolumna 21:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: linia 18, kolumna 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the cursor that way, you need to give al alias to the statement column and execute that:

```
BEGIN
    FOR v_kill IN
    (SELECT
            'alter system kill session '''
            ||sid
            ||','
            ||serial#
            || ''' immediate;' as statement
                    FROM
            v$session
                WHERE
            sql_id='sql_id_here'
    )
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line (v_kill.statement);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Also, you do not need to declare a variable to handle the cursor.

Comment: The error will likely persist with this, because there are actually two columns returned by this query.  You've aliased the second column (contains 'immediate') as statement, and that won't execute very well.  The string 'immediate' should be concatenated to the rest of the command to return the full command in one column.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I did not notice the error and copied it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Aleksej is absolutely right about syntax.

Also keep in mind that this query will kill sessions only in current instance if you run this in RAC. 
If you need to be absolutely sure to kill all sessions on all instances with your sql_id you need to use gv$session view and session id in form of 'sid,serial#,@inst_id'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'alter system kill session ''' ||sid ||','||serial#  ||',@'||inst_id||''';' from gv$session where sql_id = '&sql_id'
```